# how to restrict going to back in firefox (private window)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make a simple html and open in firefox (New Private window).I run in New private window .When I press backspace it display same screen as same when I open new private window.It completely back why? can I restrict on same page on pressing back ?
I used lot of things but nothing work .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html> 

$('html').keyup(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 8) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('backspace trapped')
        return ;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation();

})
```

Comment: pressing backspace in the browser when nothing in the window is selected highlighted and it going "back" is a functionality of the browser. If the user doesn't make the window active by clicking/scrolling in it, there is nothing you could do to disable built-in functionality in the browser

Comment: but it is not happening in chrome and firefox ..it is happening in private window

Comment: @user3036342 you have simple html and run on both chrome and firefox.nothing will happen .But when you run on firefox private window it come back

Comment: As i said, it's built into the browser to act that way, read: http://blog.laptopmag.com/disable-backspace-chrome-ie-firefox

Comment: but it is not going back in chrome and firefox..it is going back in firefox private window

Comment: any solution of this Question

Comment: its going back in chrome incognito window as well. what part of "its browser functionality" don't you understand?

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

Just insert this within head.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function noBack(){window.history.forward()}
   noBack(); 
   window.onload=noBack;
   window.onpageshow=function(evt){if(evt.persisted)noBack()}
   window.onunload=function(){void(0)}
</script>
```